# NextJs Image component with cloudinary

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, nextjs-image

I am hosting my images in Cloudinary where I do all the heavy lifting of preparing the images via transformations ( resizing the image , changing the image format to webP).

I serve these images in a NextJs App using the Image/next component :

```
<Image className={styles.bigImg} src={images[index]}  layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
```

however I noticed that Image/nextJS also automatically create different sizes to images ( more transformation in cloudinary)

what are the best practices of combining Image/nextjs with cloudinary. should I just save the original image in cloudinary and let Image/nextjs do all the heavy lifting or the oppsite.

this is the image config in next.config.js

```
images: {
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
    contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; sandbox;"
  },
```

Comment: You should do the opposite, use Cloudinary for all transformations and also store the original file there unless you want to keep a copy locally as well.

Comment: Following up on @Tom's suggestion, you can configure the [Cloudinary loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration) in `next.config.js` to do just that.